# How to sample from a probability distribution on the unit sphere?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, sampling

I'm dealing with the following problem:

"Given a set of $N$ points on the unit sphere, sample a new set of $M$ points having the same probability distribution."

I know that the simple 1D version can be solved e.g. with the inverse transform sampling method, but I couldn't find any reference on how to tackle this 3D equivalent on the unit sphere. Does anyone have good resources or hints about this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The simplest solution is to just sample from your N points as if they are the only points in the world. If you want to be able to get 'new' points then a bit more information about the probability distribution is needed

Comment: A relevant concept is [Von Mises-Fisher distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises–Fisher_distribution)

Comment: @Vincent the PDF is discrete and defined by those points. I would like to find an equivalent of the 1D case where you just have discrete points and approximate the PDF as piecewise linear, then sample from it using inverse transform.

Comment: Does the support of your distribution include only the discrete points that were sampled or do you want an approximate continuous distribution based on the points that you have?

Comment: @BrianBorchers ideally I would like to approximate the underlying continuous distribution, in order to sample from it. Not sure how to approximate it though, what I'm actually looking for is the spherical equivalent of using a piecewise linear distribution.

Comment: I think this problem is a bit underspecified to have a precise answer. If you can narrow it down to a single family of distributions, then you can do MLE on it or something. If you're looking for piecewise *constant*, you could use the points to derive a Voronoi diagram and have the density inversely proportional to the area of each zone. I'm not sure what piecewise linear would even look like on the sphere, to be honest. What's the local criterion for piecewise linear?

Answer (score 1):

1. ***Continuous Uniform Distribution.***
   The total surface of the unit sphere is
   $$
   S_2=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\sin\theta\,d\theta\,d\phi=4\pi\,,
   $$
   where $\theta,\phi$ are polar angles latitude and longitude (aka meridian). Unlike on earth, the convention here is that the north pole is at $\theta=0\,.$ One could now sample the random angles $\Theta,\Phi$ such that
   $$
   \mathbb P(\Theta\le \theta,\Phi\le\phi)=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_0^\phi\int_0^\theta\sin t\,dt\,dp=\frac{1}{4\pi}\phi\,(1-\cos\theta)\,.
   $$
   The joint distribution of $\Theta$ and $\Phi$ is obviously the product of the marginal distributions
   $$
   \mathbb P(\Theta\le\theta)=\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos\theta)\quad\text{ and }\quad\mathbb P(\Phi\le\phi)=\frac{\phi}{2\pi}\,.
   $$
   Clearly, the meridian $\Phi$ has a uniform distribution on $[0,2\pi]$ and the latitude $\Theta$ can be sampled by drawing a uniform $U\in{\cal U}(0,1)$ and inverting the marginal distribution of $\Theta:$
   $$
   \Theta=\arccos(1-2U)\,.
   $$
2. ***Discrete Uniform Distribution***. A finite number of $N$ points can be put relatively homogeneously onto the sphere when the differences in their longitudes $\phi_i$ and latitudes $\theta_i$ satisfy
   $$
   \phi_i-\phi_{i-1}=\frac{2\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{N}\sin\theta_i}\,,\quad\theta_i-\theta_{i-1}=\frac{2\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{N}}\,,\quad i=1,...,N\,.
   $$
   Clearly,
   \begin{align}
   &\mathbb P(\theta_{i-1}\le\Theta\le\theta_i,\phi_{i-1}\le\Phi\le\phi_i)
   \\[3mm]
   &=\mathbb P(\Theta\le\theta_i,\Phi\le\phi_i)
   -\mathbb P(\Theta\le\theta_i,\Phi\le\phi_{i-1})\\[3mm]
   &\quad-\mathbb P(\Theta\le\theta_{i-1},\Phi\le\phi_i)
   +\mathbb P(\Theta\le\theta_{i-1},\Phi\le \phi_{i-1})\\[3mm]
   &=\frac{\phi_i(1-\cos\theta_i)-\phi_{i-1}(1-\cos\theta_i)-\phi_i(1-\cos\theta_{i-1})+\phi_{i-1}(1-\cos\theta_{i-1})}{4\pi}\\
   &=\frac{(\cos\theta_{i-1}-\cos\theta_i)(\phi_i-\phi_{i-1})}{4\pi}\,.
   \end{align}
   For large $N$ the difference $\theta_i-\theta_{i-1}$ small so that this probability is approximately equal to
   \begin{align}
   \frac{\sin\theta_i(\theta_i-\theta_{i-1})(\phi_i-\phi_{i-1})}{4\pi}=\frac{1}{N}
   \end{align}
   which is equal for all cells $[\phi_{i-1},\phi_i]\times[\theta_{i-1},\theta_i]\,.$

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but I don't see how this is connected to having a set of points defining the PDF.

Comment: How many points? An arbitrary but finite number? If so: what have they to do with the surface of the sphere?

Comment: Yes, an arbitrary but finite number that are defined to lie on the surface of the sphere. It's simply the domain they belong to.

Answer (score 1):

You are given $N$ points on a sphere, $X=\{x_1,\dots,x_N\}$. In order to generate a new point $y$ with a similar distribution to $X$,

- Choose $x\in X$ uniformly at random.
- Choose an angle $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$ uniformly at random.
- Choose a positive number $r$ using some continuous distribution on $[0,\pi)$. The distribution should be tightly clustered near $0$. For example, the continuous uniform distribution on $[0,\pi/20]$ would work.
- Place a vector at $x$, pointing to the north pole. Rotate that vector by $\theta$, clockwise. Walk $r$ units along the direction of the rotated vector. Where you end up is the new point $y$.

Repeat this process $M$ times to generate $M$ points. Note that every point $y$ will tend to cluster where $X$ clusters, but will never be exactly equal to any of the points in $X$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, the set of points to sample must be different from the original points.

Comment: @morsingher I've edited to accommodate this new constraint.

Comment: One issue not discussed in this answer is what distribution to use for $r$.  Kernel density estimation can be used to help select the parameters of a distribution for $r$.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using a kernel density estimator to estimate the pdf and then sample from that estimated pdf as in the answer from Mike Earnest.

Although kernel density estimation with Gaussian kernels is widely used for distributions in $R^{n}$ and discussed in many textbooks, you need a version customized to work on the sphere. The von-Mises-Fisher distribution is often used instead of a Gaussian kernel.

A google search on "spherical kernel density estimation"  quickly leads to many research papers on the topic and at least one software package written in Python.

See for example:

Hall, Peter, G. S. Watson, and Javier Cabrera. "Kernel density estimation with spherical data." Biometrika 74, no. 4 (1987): 751-762.

Pelletier, Bruno. "Kernel density estimation on Riemannian manifolds." Statistics & probability letters 73, no. 3 (2005): 297-304.

Gray, Alexander G., and Andrew W. Moore. "Nonparametric density estimation: Toward computational tractability." In Proceedings of the 2003 SIAM International Conference on Data Mining, pp. 203-211. Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics, 2003.

Software:

https://github.com/williamjameshandley/spherical_kde