# Distribution of distances between random points on spheres

Tags: probability, geometry, probability-distributions, quaternions, geometric-probability

This is in relation to the following blog post by John Baez:
[Random Points on a Sphere (Part 1)](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2018/07/10/random-points-on-a-sphere-part-1/)

It is claimed that, for two unit quaternions $x,y\in S^3$, uniformly randomly selected, the probability distribution of $|xy-yx|$ (how "far apart" $x$ and $y$ are from commuting) is given by:
$$ P(d) = d-\frac{2d\arcsin(d/2)}{\pi},\quad d = |xy-yx|,\quad x,y\in S^3. $$
More generally, the probability distribution for the distance between two uniformly randomly chosen points on the $n$-sphere is given by:
$$P_n(d) = \frac{d^{n-2}(4-d^2)^{\frac{n-3}{2}}\Gamma(n/2)}{2^{n-3}\sqrt{\pi}\ \Gamma(\frac{n-1}{2})},\quad d=|x-y|,\quad x,y\in S^n.$$
My knowledge of probability theory is in all honesty, severely lacking. So my question is:

> Q: How does one derive these probability distributions?

Comment: Maybe related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4504902/distribution-of-cosine-of-angle-between-random-vectors-in-d-dimensional-space/4505679#4505679

Comment: Also [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4382070/949989) and hopefully a bit self contained. Baez' formulas are impressive and it would not surprise me if they are the results of hard work. If you want to start in probability theory you may want to derive CDFs/PDFs of simpler distributions in $\mathbb R$ or an interval first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be clear, the formulas are probability densities, not cumulative distributions. The hypersphere formula is not a generalization of the quaternion formula, though similar math is involved in both. Also note the hypersphere formula you gave is for $S^{n-1}$ not $S^n$.

---

Let $F(d)=\mathrm{Prob}(|x-y|\le d\mid x,y\in S^{n-1})$ be the cumulative distribution for the distance between two points chosen uniformly at random from the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$. By symmetry, we can let $y$ be any fixed unit vector. The set of $x$ for which $|x-y|\le d$ is a hyperspherical cap enclosed in a hyperspherical sphere of spherical radius $\theta$ around $y$ defined by

$$d^2=(1-\cos\theta)^2+\sin^2\theta=2(1-\cos\theta). $$

[Try drawing this for $n=3$ as a visual aid for where the Pythagorean theorem comes in.] Then $F(d)$ will be the area of this cap divided by the total "area" of the sphere.

Let $A_{n-1}=2\pi^{n/2}/\Gamma(n/2)$ be the total area of the $(n-1)$-dimensional sphere $S^{n-1}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. [This formula is derived in many places using recursion, induction, substitution.] Since the cap is a hypersurface of revolution we may take advantage of symmetry to calculate its "area." It can be sliced into cross-sections which are $(n-2)$-spheres of Euclidean radius $\sin\phi$ as the angle $\phi$ from $y$ varies from $0$ to $\theta$. By integrating the content of these slices with respect to $\phi$ we get the CDF

$$ F(d)=\frac{1}{A_{n-1}}\int_0^\theta A_{n-2}(\sin\phi)^{n-2}\,\mathrm{d}\phi. $$

Differentiating WRT $\theta$ then yields the PDF

$$ f(d)\frac{\mathrm{d}d}{\mathrm{d}\theta} = \frac{A_{n-2}}{A_{n-1}}(\sin\theta)^{n-2}. $$

To start simplifying this we need $d$ and $\mathrm{d}d/\mathrm{d}\theta$ in terms of $d$. Differentiate $d^2=\cdots$ to get

$$ 2d\frac{\mathrm{d}d}{\mathrm{d}\theta}=2\sin\theta \quad\Rightarrow\quad \frac{\mathrm{d}d}{\mathrm{d}\theta}=\frac{\sin\theta}{d}. $$

Also $\cos\theta=1-d^2/2$ so $\sin\theta=\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}=\sqrt{1-(1-d^2/2)^2}=d\sqrt{1-(d/2)^2}$. Now

$$ f(d)\frac{\sin\theta}{d}=\frac{A_{n-2}}{A_{n-1}}(\sin\theta)^{n-2} \implies $$

$$ f(d)=\frac{A_{n-2}}{A_{n-1}}d(\sin\theta)^{n-3}$$

Substituting in for the $A$s and $\sin\theta$ yields

$$ f(d)=\frac{2\pi^{(n-2)/2}/\Gamma(\frac{n-1}{2})}{2\pi^{n/2}/\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})} d\left(d\sqrt{1-\Big(\frac{d}{2}\Big)^2}\,\right)^{n-3} $$

which simplifies to the given formula

$$ f_{|x-y|}(d)=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})d^{n-2}(4-d^2)^{(n-3)/2}}{2^{n-3}\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(\frac{n-1}{2})} \quad (0\le d\le2). \tag{$\bullet$}$$

---

To compute the density for $|xy-yx|$ with $x,y\in S^3$ (for versors, aka unit quaternions, drawn uniformly at random WRT the usual Lebesgue measure), write $x,y$ in polar form as $x=\exp(\alpha\mathbf{u})$, $y=\exp(\beta\mathbf{v})$ and let $\angle\mathbf{uv}=\gamma$ be the angle between $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$. Using convex angles only, these are uniquely defined for all $x,y\ne\pm1$ (measure zero, so no worries). Note $\alpha,\beta,\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}$ are all independent random variables in their own right, with $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\in S^2$ drawn uniformly at random. Then the commutator magnitude is given by

$$|xy-yx|=2|\mathrm{Im}(x)\times\mathrm{Im}(y)|=2|\mathrm{Im}(x)||\mathrm{Im}(y)||\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{v}|=2\sin\alpha\sin\beta\sin\gamma. $$

The CDFs of $\sin\alpha,\sin\beta,\sin\gamma$ will all be calculated using spherical caps again, the first two in $S^3$ and the third in $S^2$. The set of all unit vectors whose convex angle $\psi$ made with a given unit vector satisfies $\sin\psi\le d$ is a pair of antipodal spherical caps with spherical radius $\delta$ and Euclidean radius $\sin\delta=d$. For a general sphere $S^{n-1}$ we have thus have the CDF

$$ F_{\sin\delta}(d) = \frac{2}{A_{n-1}}\int_0^\delta A_{n-2}(\sin\psi)^{n-2}\,\mathrm{d}\psi. $$

and differentiating WRT $\delta$ yields

$$ f_{\sin\delta}(d)\cos\delta = \frac{2A_{n-2}}{A_{n-1}}(\sin\delta)^{n-2} $$

which means the PDF is given by

$$ f_{\sin\delta}(d)=\frac{2A_{n-2}}{A_{n-1}}\frac{d^{n-2}}{\sqrt{1-d^2}} $$

Setting $n=4,4,3$ (for $S^3,S^3,S^2$ resp.) we get PDFs

$$ f_{\sin\alpha}(a)=\frac{4}{\pi}\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}, \quad f_{\sin\beta}(b)=\frac{4}{\pi}\frac{b^2}{\sqrt{1-b^2}}, \quad f_{\sin\gamma}(c)=\frac{c}{\sqrt{1-c^2}}.~ $$

Convolving these three PDFs gives us the original CDF

$$ F_{|xy-yx|}(d)=\Big(\frac{4}{\pi}\Big)^2\!\iiint\limits_{2abc\le d}\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}\frac{b^2}{\sqrt{1-b^2}}\frac{c}{\sqrt{1-c^2}}\,\mathrm{d}c\,\mathrm{d}b\,\mathrm{d}a. $$

For better parametrization, consider the complement

$$ 1-\Big(\frac{4}{\pi}\Big)^2\!\!\iiint\limits_{abc\ge d/2}\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}\frac{b^2}{\sqrt{1-b^2}}\frac{c}{\sqrt{1-c^2}}\,\mathrm{d}c\,\mathrm{d}b\,\mathrm{d}a $$

which can now be turned into an iterated integral

$$1-\Big(\frac{4}{\pi}\Big)^2\!\int_{d/2}^1 \frac{a^2}{\sqrt{1-a^2}} \left(\int_{d/2a}^1 \frac{b^2}{\sqrt{1-b^2}} \left(\int_{d/2ab}^1 \frac{c}{\sqrt{1-c^2}}\,\mathrm{d}c\right)\mathrm{d}b\right)\mathrm{d}a. $$

It is possible to evaluate this directly, but for the density we can now differentiate WRT $d$ using the Leibniz integral rule. Despite this being a triple integral, all resulting terms vanish except where we apply the FTC to the innermost integral. The PDF $f_{|xy-yx|}(d)$ is thus given by

$$ -\Big(\frac{4}{\pi}\Big)^2\!\int_{d/2}^1 \frac{a^2}{\sqrt{1-a^2}} \Bigg(\int_{d/2a}^1 \frac{b^2}{\sqrt{1-b^2}} \frac{\frac{d}{2ab}(-\frac{1}{2ab})}{\sqrt{1-(\frac{d}{2ab})^2}}\,\mathrm{d}b\Bigg)\mathrm{d}a. $$

We can simplify this to

$$ \frac{4d}{\pi^2}\int_{d/2}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-a^2}} \Bigg(\int_{d/2a}^1 \frac{b}{\sqrt{(1-b^2)(b^2-(\frac{d}{2a})^2)}}\,\mathrm{d}b\Bigg)\mathrm{d}a $$

To evaluate the inner integral, set $k=\frac{d}{2a}$ and substitute $\ell=\sqrt{b^2-k^2}$ then $m=\ell/\sqrt{1-k^2}$:

$$ \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-b^2}} \frac{b\,\mathrm{d}b}{\sqrt{b^2-k^2}}=\int \frac{\mathrm{d}\sqrt{b^2-k^2}}{\sqrt{1-b^2}}=\int \frac{\mathrm{d}\ell}{\sqrt{(1-k^2)-\ell^2}} = $$

$$ \int\frac{\mathrm{d}\Big(\frac{\ell}{\sqrt{1-k^2}}\Big)}{\sqrt{1-\big(\frac{\ell}{\sqrt{1-k^2}}\big)^2}}=\int\frac{\mathrm{d}m}{\sqrt{1-m^2}}=\sin^{-1}(m)=\sin^{-1}\!\Big(\sqrt{\frac{b^2-k^2}{1-k^2}}\,\Big). $$

Therefore the inner integral evaluates simply to

$$ \int_k^1 \frac{b\,\mathrm{d}b}{\sqrt{(1-b^2)(b^2-k^2)}}=\Bigg[\sin^{-1}\!\Big(\sqrt{\frac{b^2-k^2}{1-k^2}}\,\Big)\Bigg]_k^1=\frac{\pi}{2}. $$

So now what we have is

$$ f(d)=\frac{4d}{\pi^2}\int_{d/2}^1\frac{\mathrm{d}a}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}\frac{\pi}{2} $$

which evaluates simply to

$$ f_{|xy-yx|}(d)=\frac{2d}{\pi}\cos^{-1}\Big(\frac{d}{2}\Big) \quad(0\le d\le2), \tag{$\large\star$}$$

which matches the given formula.

Comment: absolutely fantastic! Thank you!